# Запуск python с параметрами, как сделать?

Tags: python

Допустим я хочу запускать файл вот так:
`python main.py param1 param2`
И хочу чтобы в самом файле было так

```
a=param1
b=param2
```

Comment: примите ответ, если он вам помог — ­галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys

a = b = ''
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        a = sys.argv[1]
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        b = sys.argv[2]

    print(f'a = {a}, b = {b}')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import sys

a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]
```

`sys.argv` - список параметров запуска. Первым параметром получается имя запускаемого файла. Однако стоит учитывает, что пользователь может и не указать параметры при запуске, что приведёт к ошибке.

Пусть файл с кодом выше называется `test.py`. Запустим его командой:

```
python test.py hello 412
```

Тогда `sys.argv` равен `['test.py', 'hello', '412']`
Также обращаю внимание на то, что этот список всегда содержит именно строковые значения, и это тоже может быть важно (например, название функции или None туда передать будет затруднительно)

Comment: Возьму на заметку